# "dynamic" vs "dynamics"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

What's the difference between the two. For example, should I say:

> I thought the **dynamic** of our relationship had been enough for her.

or

I thought the **dynamics** of our relationship had been enough for her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a plural, just like u might expect. A dynamic is a chain of cause and effect. dynamics relate to interactive but distinguishable chains of cause and effect that interact either catalysticly, or exponentially.

Comment: Dynamics is also a musical term. Just saying.